# Angular2 lazy loaded app bundle of main.js using browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, bundle, browserify

I'm trying to bundle main.js using this command of browserify.

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

than I changed systemjs.config file and updated path of main from main.js to bundle.js.

```
app: {
    main: './bundle.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
```

1st module(One which isn't lazy loaded) is working as expected.But it shows this zone.js error message in console.
[image]

and as I try to access lazy loaded page it won't execute and throws this error in console.
[image]

Where am I doing wrong?